# Why I need to add .jar file into libs derectory if libs is being generated?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, chartboost

In [Chartboost's Android tutorial](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201219545) there is a step when I need to add `chartboost.jar`, `chartboost.jar.properties`, and the `doc` folder into my project's `libs` folder. But `libs`, `obj`, `bin` directories are being generated compile time, right? I even don't have them in my repo. I added them to my ignore list. Why I need to create and add in them any files? Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libs` won't be generated at compile time. It is place where you keep your external library `.jar` files.

You should not ignore `libs` folder in your `.gitignore`

[Check this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/) as a template for your `.gitignore`

Comment: Oops! :) I ignored `lib`. But https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore is ignores `bin/` and `gen/` should I also consider `obj` folder? Cause I have ignored it too :D

Comment: @Narek: There is no `obj/` folder in the project root in standard Android projects.

Comment: @CommonsWare but in my case it is being generated. This should be because it is an NDK project.

Comment: @Narek: Ah, good point. I forgot about that. Yes, I would filter `obj/` out from version control via `.gitignore`.